# Time dilation due to gravitational potential

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

What is the theoretical reason to substitute escape velocity equation in the time dilation equation of relative motion to get time dilation equation due to gravitational potential?

The time dilation equation is:

$$ t'=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \tag{1} $$

And the escape velocity equation is:

$$ v_{\text{esc}} = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}} \tag{2} $$

And if we use equation (2) to substitute for $v$ in equation (1) we get:

$$ t'=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}}} \tag{3} $$

Which is the correct equation for gravitational time dilation.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of equations, as pictures are not accessible to all users. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format variables and equations.

Comment: @AaronStevens thanks a lot

Comment: Once I finish going through Math Jack I will not post photos of equations. By then can someone edit the question by adding the equation for me. It would be great help.

Comment: I have done the first one as an example for you.

Comment: @AaronStevens 

Answer (score 0):

The question of possibility to derive the Schwarzschild metric based only on Special relativity (without the use of GR) historically was raised by Lenz. A. Sommerfeld reported his ideas in Lectures on Theoretical Physics in 1944. In 60ths Sacks W.M. and Shiﬀ et al were discussing this topic again.

I suggest you refer to:

Czerniawski J. The possibility of a simple derivation of the
Schwarzschild metric. arXiv: gr-qc/0611104,

Czerniawski J. What is wrong with Schwarzschild’s coordinates? arXiv: gr-qc/0201037

Visser M. Heuristic Approach to the Schwarzschild geometry, arXiv: gr-qc/0309072

For recent model development, it is worth to mention "The river model of black holes" by Hamilton and Lisle.